# How to stub requests on domain or after method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

```
config.before(:each) do
  stub_request(:post, "https://api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com/send.php?body=This%20is%20a%20test%20message&destination=60123456789&dlr='1'&output=json&password=0000000&reference=#{@text.sms_uid}&sender=silver&username=0000000").
    to_return(:status => 200, :body => "01", :headers => {})
end
```

I am currently writing specs for a service class that sends an SMS and creates a log of it in our database. I'm trying to stub this request, however `@text.sms_uid` is a `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` random code. Also I'm stubbing in `config.before(:each)`.

Because of that, I can't specify the `sms_uid` in `stub_request` as the random `sms_uid` is generated after the stub is called. This causes the test to fail every time. Is there a way I can stub the request after it generates the code (in other words, after it goes through the specific method) or is there a way to stub all requests going through the domain "https://api.silverstreet.com"?

Comment: Which spec file did you add this to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

- Stub `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` to return a known string and use that known string when you `stub_request`:

  ```
  config.before(:each) do
    known_string = "known-string"
    allow(SecureRandom).to receive(:known_string) { known_string }
    stub_request(:post, "https://api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com/send.php?body=This%20is%20a%20test%20message&destination=60123456789&dlr='1'&output=json&password=0000000&reference=#{known_string}&sender=silver&username=0000000").
      to_return(status: 200, body: "01", headers: {})
  end
  ```

  If `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` is used in other places in your application, you'll need to stub it only in the specs where this request is generated.
- Yes, you can stub any POST to that hostname

  ```
  stub_request(:post, "api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com").
    to_return(status: 200, body: "01", headers: {})
  ```

  or even any request of any kind to that hostname

  ```
  stub_request(:any, "api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com").
    to_return(status: 200, body: "01", headers: {})
  ```

  and [webmock has a very large number of other ways to match requests](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I had no idea I could stub SecureRandom. Anyway, I managed to solve it using regex 

`stub_request(:post, %r{https://api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com}).
      to_return(:status => 200, :body => "01", :headers => {})`

which is basically

`stub_request(:post, "api.3rdpartysmsprovider.com").
  to_return(status: 200, body: "01", headers: {})`

except for some reason stubbing it as a string didn't work for me